# Is it '봉투 하나' or '봉투 한 장'?

Tags: translation, korean-to-english

What is the proper expression when asking for a plastic bag, for example, at a shop?

Would it be 봉투 하나 주세요? or 봉투 한 장 주세요?

Comment: Is the proper expression "Give me a sheet of paper," or "Give me a piece of paper"? Personally I think it is the same case here.

Comment: There should be a space between 한 and 장. For example, 한 장, 두 개, 세 명, and so on. A word to express quantity and a noun comes after should be written leaving space.

Comment: @jungyh0218 Please don't hesitate to edit a post when you find a typo. Editing a post helps the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless there were any reason to assume a number other than one, just saying 봉투 주세요 would be fine. 봉투 하나 주세요 is also fine, and removes any doubt that only one is needed. 봉투 한 장 주세요 is the most 'proper', but even in Korean, sometimes most proper isn't the most common or appropriate - it could sound like you are over-egging the pudding.

When a number is needed, you might even hear Koreans just saying 봉투 두 개 주세요, even though 개 isn't the most specific 세는 단위 (counting unit) for 봉투.

Comment: Hi, topo morto. I understand what you are trying to mean, but I think it is a little misleading to say "even though 개 isn't the right 수사" as '수사' means '사물의 수량이나 순서를 나타내는 품사. '개' has nothing to do with '수사' in the first place. Also, there should be a space between '한' and '장' and '두' and '개'.

Comment: @Rathony perhaps I should have said "not the right 수분류사" - would that make more sense?

Comment: Well, it makes sense, but I don't see the word '수분류사' in a dictionary. It would make more sense if you use "세는 단위 (literally, counting unit)" in place of '수사'. '개' is a '의존명사 (dependent noun)' in terms of part of speech.

Comment: @Rathony I hope my edits are an improvement but feel free to tidy up if not.

Comment: It reads better than before. However, I would be reluctant to say "개 is not the right 세는 단위" as '개' is the most broadly used 세는 단위 in Korean and '봉투 한 개 or 두 개' is perfectly idiomatic. I don't see any difference between  '봉투 한 장' and '봉투 한 개'. It's just my opinion and I don't think it is appropriate to edit your answer based on my opinion.